# Progress works EXCEPT with Mobile Safari on iPhone

Tags: javascript, php, progress-bar, mobile-safari

I have the PECL module installed. Everything works fine. The progress bar is doing it's job. It works on all desktop browsers, on Android browsers, but the progress is NOT showing on Safari/iPhone (iOS 7.0.6 iPhone5 and older versions iPhone4). The files do get uploaded, but you will only see (after a while) 100% for a brief moment, than the script shows "upload complete". Hope someone can help me out.

```
        <?php
    if ($_POST['progress'] == "show") { 
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/files/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path);
    }
    exit; }

    if ($_GET['getprogress'] == "1") { 
    if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {
        // Fetch the upload progress data
        $status = uploadprogress_get_info($_GET['uid']);
        if ($status) {
            // Calculate the current percentage
            echo round($status['bytes_uploaded']/$status['bytes_total']*100);
        }
        else {
            // If there is no data, assume it's done
            echo 100;
        }
    }
    exit; }

    // Generate random string for our upload identifier
    $uid = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
            <title>Upload Something</title>
            <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                #progress-bar, #upload-frame, #upload-result {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
                (function ($) {

                    // We'll use this to cache the progress bar node
                    var pbar;

                    // This flag determines if the upload has started
                    var started = false;

                    $(function () {

                        // Start progress tracking when the form is submitted
                        $('#upload-form').submit(function() {

                            // Hide the form
                            $('#upload-form').hide();

                            // Cache the progress bar
                            pbar = $('#progress-bar');

                            // Show the progress bar
                            // Initialize the jQuery UI plugin
                            pbar.show().progressbar();

                            // We know the upload is complete when the frame loads
                            $('#upload-frame').load(function () {

                                // This is to prevent infinite loop
                                // in case the upload is too fast
                                started = true;

                                // Do whatever you want when upload is complete
                                 $('#progress-bar').hide();
                                 $("#progress-result").html('upload complete');

                            });

                            // Start updating progress after a 1 second delay
                            setTimeout(function () {

                                // We pass the upload identifier to our function
                                updateProgress($('#uid').val());

                            }, 1000);

                        });

                    });

                    function updateProgress(id) {

                        var time = new Date().getTime();

                        // Make a GET request to the server
                        // Pass our upload identifier as a parameter
                        // Also pass current time to prevent caching
                        $.get('/upload/index.php?getprogress=1', { uid: id, t: time }, function (data) {

                            // Get the output as an integer
                            var progress = parseInt(data, 10);

                            if (progress < 100 || !started) {

                                // Determine if upload has started
                                started = progress < 100;

                                // If we aren't done or started, update again
                                updateProgress(id);

                            }

                            // Update the progress bar percentage
                            // But only if we have started
                            started && pbar.progressbar('value', progress);

                        });

                    }

                }(jQuery));
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" target="upload-frame">
                <input type="hidden" id="uid" name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="progress" name="progress" value="show">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!">
            </form>
            <div id="progress-bar"></div>
            <div id="progress-result"></div>
            <iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame"></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2 ? Recommend to update to newer version. Which iOS version ?

Comment: I've tried jQuery 1.9.1 (even 2.1.0). The issue is on latest iOS with iPhone5, but also older versions. The files are being uploaded, but with iOS it seems that the progress is not showing every second.

Comment: since your progress is obtained by GET HTTP request, it must have network delay. My guess is Mobile Safari has sort of limits in HTTP request frequency, but not sure.